# Is there a meta version of this site?

Tags: brewing, meta

On other stack exchange forums, there are meta forums to hash out goals, methods and moderator guidelines. Does HBSE have the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes, it is here](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/), and it seems to be used.