# Are you aware of Homebrew Meta?

Tags: meta

This is a quick one. Are you aware of the meta side of this site?

https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/

Did you know this existsed before now?

=== The election happened, but the above is still valid ===

Just thought I would try to make people more aware of this side of the site as we have some moderator elections coming up and I am worried people will be unaware of this and as such may miss out.

[Announcing a Pro Tempore election](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election)

HB.SE is telling me "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed", I know see below:

- If you think this is of no value: comment or flag and I will happily remove it;
- But, if you think making more people aware of the full HB.SE community is a valid use of a question then please comment with other features people may be unaware of.

Comment: potential duplicate
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/22173/3352
Just kidding :-)

Comment: I really think we could make more use of that chat section.

Comment: this one: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/199/homebrew

Comment: Yes- however I think we should focus on making the chat a little more active rather than Meta. Meta is a place to ask questions about the structure of a community... we don't have a ton of community here these days. Can we unfreeze the chat!?

Comment: I will have a look into this

Comment: @rob - I don't seem to be able to unfreeze a room but I can make a new one here we go - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115783/se-homebrew-chat

Comment: May have to make another question saying do people know that Homebrew Chat rooms exist :D